# Android: How to access/manage cached files after an app restart?

Tags: android, caching, temporary-files

Looking at the docs when it comes to caching, it seems I'm supposed to use [createTempFile()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html), but if the call succeeds, it always creates an empty file. And even if called again with the same arguments, it won't return the same filename.

1. So if I restart the app, do I not have a way to retrieve a temporary file?
2. If I wanted to implement an LRU algorithm for removing files from the cache, does creating a normal (non-temporary) file with key value pairs of filenames and timestamps seem reasonable? (Since I don't think android updates any sort last accessed times for files)

Comment: If you need a temporary file, make it permanent

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Thank you.  As simple as that statement is, it cleared up my confusion.  The docs (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) come off a little misleading because they say for any cache related files, use createTempFile(). But they don't really define what "temporary" means or mention that caching files this way isn't meant to be used after the app is reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably manage the cached files in memory alone.  Create a separate directory for cache files and use the in memory LRU singleton class for managing the files.  Each time the app is restarted, scan the cache directory and reload your LRU cache from the directory contents.  You will loose your cache statistics on restart, if that's a bad thing it can probably be handled when paused.

Managing the cache in memory will be much faster than writing and re-writing a key-value pair file.

How many files do you intend to keep in the cache?

Comment: Probably about 300-400 MB worth (caching videos). When you say "create a separate directory for cache files", do you recommend using permanent or temporary files?

Comment: If you want the cache to survive app restarts then you will need to go with permanent files.  300+ video files can consume a lot of space.

Comment: Thank you.  And 300 MB worth of videos, not 300 videos :P I've decided to start out with a simple disk cache and as you suggested, reset the LRU algorithm on app restarts instead of trying to preserve its previous state (unless I really need to for whatever reason later on). And if I'm not happy with the performance of the disk cache, I'll use the LRU singleton class to have a cache in memory as you suggested. Thank you!